# Export variables from SASS to vanilla CSS?

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

Consider I have a long list of SASS variables in different `.scss` files like this:

```
$app-color-white: #ffffff;
$app-color-black: #000000;
```

What would be the most effective way to export these variables as vanilla CSS variables?

```
:root {
  --app-color-white: #ffffff;
  --app-color-black: #000000;
}
```

Maybe, there is a SASS-way or even some pre-processor?

I want my SASS framework to be also used in vanilla CSS projects.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible thanks to [sass modules](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) and the new [`sass:meta.module-variables()`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/meta#module-variables) function: it

> Returns all the variables defined in a module, as a map from variable names (without $) to the values of those variables.

For example

```
// _vars.scss

$color: red;
$font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

```
// style.scss

@use 'sass:meta';
@use 'vars';

:root {
  @each $name, $value in meta.module-variables(vars) {
    --#{$name}: #{$value};
  }
}
```

Outputs

```css
:root {
  --color: red;
  --font: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

> ⚠️ Sass modules are currently only supported in Dart Sass

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this would be using something like a variable map;

E.g.

```
// sass variable map
$colors: (
  primary: #FFBB00,
  secondary: #0969A2
);

// ripped CSS4 vars out of color map
:root {
  // each item in color map
  @each $name, $color in $colors {
    --color-#{$name}: $color;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
:root {
  --color-primary: #FFBB00;
  --color-secondary: #0969A2;
}
```

Source: https://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/post/css4-variables-and-sass

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about such approach, but using variables in SASS this way becomes cumbersome, because you have to use getter functions like `map-get` and I believe IDEs doesn't support SASS maps very well. I don't want to sacrifice Developer Experience in SASS for this.