# SCSS external Link to styling component in LitElement

Tags: javascript, sass, web-component, lit-element

The purpose of the web components is to encapsulate all HTML/CSS/JS in one place, but I must use general SCSS files, that have a lot of variables such as color, font size and a lot of other stuff. It's a design system and it's always changing. Is there a plugin or a way to solve this problem?

Comment: By `have a lot of variables` you mean that these SCSS files _only_ contain variables or do they also style some elements?

Comment: thank you for your comment.
exactly, SCSS file für the colors and file for the font and etc...

Answer (score 1):

If the purpose of those Sass files is to *only* expose some variables then probably the smartest thing to do is [converting them to CSS custom properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047216/6193024): they're the [recommended](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#customprops) and most effective way to theme WebComponents.

```
@use 'sass:meta';
@use 'variables-file-1'; // Import the variable files
@use 'variables-file-2'; // as Sass modules
// ...

@mixin export-vars($module-name) {
  // Use module-variables() to extract a name-to-value map of the
  // variables declared in the module identified by $module-name
  @each $name, $value in meta.module-variables($module-name) {
    --#{$name}: #{$value}; // Define an equivalent CSS custom prop
  }
}


:root {
  @include export-vars(variables-file-1);
  @include export-vars(variables-file-2);
  // ...
}
```

You can then import the compiled CSS (a normal `<link>` in `index.html` is fine in most cases since CSS custom properties cross shadow DOM boundaries) and use the variables in your components:

```js
import { LitElement, html, css, customElement } from 'lit-element';

@customElement('my-component')
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {

  static styles = css`
    :host {
      color: var(--my-var, <fallback-value>);
    }
  `;

}
```

With this said, if you need to share styles between LitElements, that [is possible](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#sharing-styles) as well.