# Extract all Bootstrap 4.6 variables in a css file for using it in Figma

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass, figma

I need to export all variables from bootstrap\scss_variables.scss (boostrap-4.6.2) in a css file to import those variables in Figma.

I failed to convert it with sass. I got this error :

```
sass _variables.scss _variables.css
Error: $color: theme-color("primary") is not a color.
    ╷
178 │ $link-hover-color:                        darken($link-color, 15%) !default;
    │                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  _variables.scss 178:43  root stylesheet
```

I'm a completly newbie with sass... Could you please help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Already answerd at 
  [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536228/export-sass-scss-variables-to-javascript-without-exporting-them-to-css
 AND  [2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785846/export-variables-from-sass-to-vanilla-css

Comment: I did everything as explain in the second post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51785846/export-variables-from-sass-to-vanilla-css) with the following code :
`
@use 'bootstrap/scss/_functions';
@use 'bootstrap/scss/_variables';
@use 'sass:meta';

:root {
  @each $name, $value in meta.module-variables(variables) {
    --#{$name}: #{$value};
  }
}
`

But I still have the same error ;
sass app.scss compiled.css
`
Error: $color: theme-color("primary") is not a color.
`

Comment: 1. You intend to export all varaibles from `bootstrap\scss_variables.scss` to another `css` file and then want to Import from that intermediate `css` file. Correct? 2. Check if  `theme-color()` is a  `sass` function and you are passing parameters correctly.